# Simple php ajax html issue

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

simple question for most of you but for me, being a newbie in php and jquery+ajax, not really: how to replace my index.html with some other html code, requested by ajax call from a php file?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

   <h1>Login page</h1>

   <button id="btn_login">Login</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**javascript.js**

```
$('#btn_login').click(
function(){

   $.ajax({
      url: "login.php",
      type: "GET",
      success: function(data){
          // what to do here?
      }
   });
}
)
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
echo '<div>Succesful login</div>';
?>
```

TLDR: I want to replace the "Login page" + login button screen to "Succesful login" when clicked the button.
Thank you

Comment: $('#btn_login').html("Succesful login");

Comment: i wish it was this easy, but i must use php for the solution, it is a requirement.

Comment: There is no harm to use this code inside ajax as ,you are dealing with server by ajax.

Comment: please mark an answer as solved if this closed your issue. Open new question in case you need

Answer (score 0):

you need to identify -or classify- your `<h1>` tag to be easily able to change 
it's contents ,

```
<h1 id='title'>Login page</h1>
```

then , within your ajax call, if success you can change the content like that:

```
success: function(data){
    // what to do here?
    if (data) {
        $('#title').html(data);
        $('#btn_login').remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look: ( https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first **:** [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) )
...

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
$('#btn_login').click(
function(){

       $.ajax({
          url: "login.php",
          type: "GET",
          success: function(data){
              document.body.innerHTML = ""; // remove all content from the document
              document.write(data); // write the returned div to the document
          }
       });
    }
    )
```

Comment: i have no idea either, your solution seems to work just as well as other's here, thanks